# What's the origin and meaning of the adjective "free" in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, abstract-algebra

It's pretty common to call a group, ring or module free when it has a 'basis', but unlike other mathematical definitions whose names can be easily related to the concept they describe (*e.g.* the *spectrum* of an operator), the name *free* hardly tells me anything intuitively about the object itself. So, the questions are:

What's the origin of this terminology?

Is there any hint on what the original motivation was?

Comment: You think that *spectrum* easily connects to the concept it describes?? I'd say it's a pretty colorful nomenclature (pun intended).

Comment: Well, it clearly resembles the use given by the physicists. From Wikipedia: *In Latin spectrum means "image" or "apparition", including the meaning "spectre".*

Comment: I'd argue that this is only true once you internalized the mathematical notion denoted by "image". E.g. the most common operator will be a matrix, a block of numbers, and its "action" is (if you got a field of characteristic zero) on infinite different vectors and there just by multiplication of these vectors by a number. I don't really see how this "clearly resembles the use given by the physicists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Free" usually means "free of relations", "independent".
For example, a free group is the set of all words in a given alphabet
$$a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}, c, c^{-1}\ldots .$$
The group operation is concatenation of words, with cancellation of $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$.
the neutral element is the empty word.

Every finitely generated group can be presented in a similar way but with certain "relations" that is several words which are equal to the neutral word by definition.

Then we have a homeomorphism from the free group to any other group generated by the same
alphabet. This situation can be formalized in terms of category theory, and in any category
a "free object" can be defined using the appropriate morphism diagram.

Reference: S. Lang, Algebra.

Comment: And is there some reason to think these are "origin" or "original motivation" for the term?